# How to get x number of rows for each unique column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table and here is the values.

```
id      photo_name      user_id     created_at
----------------------------------------------
144     Photo1          1           2014-05-01 09:30:15
143     Photo2          2           2014-05-01 10:30:15
142     Photo3          1           2014-05-01 11:30:15
141     Photo4          3           2014-05-01 12:30:15
140     Photo5          1           2014-05-01 13:30:15
139     Photo6          2           2014-05-01 14:30:15
139     Photo6          2           2014-05-01 14:30:15
```

**Expected result**

I want to **limit** **2** photos per user_id

```
id      photo_name      user_id     created_at
----------------------------------------------
144     Photo1          1           2014-05-01 11:30:15
142     Photo3          1           2014-05-01 12:30:15
143     Photo2          2           2014-05-01 13:30:15
139     Photo6          2           2014-05-01 14:30:15
141     Photo4          3           2014-05-01 14:30:15
```

I've tried several ways but couldn't get the desired result. Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in MySQL is to use variables:

```
select id, photo_name, user_id, created_at
from (select p.*,
             @rn := if(@uid = user_id, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @uid := user_id
      from photos p cross join
           (select @uid := -1, @rn := 0) var
      order by user_id
     ) p
where rn <= 2;
```

There is another way using standard SQL:

```
select p.*
from photos p
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from photos p2
            where p2.user_id = p.user_id and
                  p2.id <= p.id
           );
```

What the subquery query does is count the number of photos by a given user.  The `p2.user_id = p.user_id` restricts the query to just the user.  The `p2.id <= p.id` puts in an ordering.  So the lowest `id` for a user has only one match (itself) and the count is `1`.  The next has two matches -- the lowest and itself -- so the value is 2.  And so on.

Comment: Can you help to explain the usage of "p2.id <= p.id" here? Thanks